# How can I extract code into its own class while still calling a protected method?

Tags: ruby, protected

I was hoping to extract a lot of logic into a separate class in the following code, but I am having trouble with that since it ends up calling a protected method.

This is my current code:

```
class ExcelSheet
  ...
  protected

  def save_stuff
    # do work
  end
end

class CustomSheet < ExcelSheet
  def custom_stuff
    # lots of logic
    save_stuff
    # more logic
  end
end
```

This was my attempted code:

```
class LogicManager
  def logic_valid?
    # lots of logic
    save_stuff
  end
end

class CustomSheet < ExcelSheet
  def custom_stuff
    manager = LogicManager.new(some_data)
    if manager.logic_valid?
      # more logic
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately in my `LogicManager` I can't call `save_stuff` because it's `protected`. I didn't write the original method, and I'm sure it's marked as `protected` for a reason, so I don't think I should change that.

What options do I have to still refactor nicely?

Comment: Is the `LogicClass` supposed to be a child of `ExcelSheet`? I don't see how you expect to call the method in that class when it doesn't exist unless you have it defined elsewhere?

Comment: I've added some more detail. This is the first way I could think of to try to simplify the code a bit.

Comment: I see the edits, however I still don't see how you expect to call `save_stuff` from the `logic_valid?` method in your `LogicManager` class. The way it currently stands the `save_stuff` method is defined in `ExcelSheet` which has no relation to the `LogicManager` class.

Comment: I think you just want to move the `save_stuff` from the `logic_valid?` method info the if block in the `custom_stuff` method

Comment: Ahh yes, I apologize for misunderstanding your question. You're right, I would have a tough time calling `save_stuff` from within `logic_valid?`. I can't move `save_stuff` from where it is, as a ton of other classes in the project are using it. I'll do some more thinking tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a bit of a misunderstanding of `protected` methods.

Protected methods can be invoked only by the class that defines it, or by it's subclasses. In your case, it means that if you would like to invoke the method `save_stuff` in the class `LogicManager`, that means that `LogicManager` must inherit from `ExcelSheet`.

Given the naming of the classes, I am not sure if you want to do that as it doesn't seem logical to me (no pun intended).

Comment: That crossed my mind, I completely agree. I don't think it should inherit from `ExcelSheet` either because it's not a sheet. I was just trying to extract code elsewhere. Maybe I'm going about this all wrong. I'll do more thinking tomorrow.

Comment: If it makes sense, extract `save_stuff` to a module and include it (mixin) in the needed classes? Just be aware that that will make it a public method across all of them.